# Очистить проект после обновления c git

Tags: xcode, git, objective-c

Проблема в том, что заказчик не понимает, что каждый раз после скачивания проекта с Git нужно делать проекту clean дабы избежать непонятных ошибок.

Вопрос таков: как можно запустить clean проекту на Xcode каждый раз, когда он делает обновления?

Comment: > каждый раз после скачивания проекта с гит нужно делать проекту clean дабы избежать непонятных ошибок

Обычно это значит, что в репозиторий закоммитили мусорные проектные файлы.

Comment: не факт, это также может означать изменение ресурсов (например, ксибы или локализация - они любят застревать), да и объектники иногда бывает залипают - сам видел проект запускавшийся у разраба, но не из репозитория - оказалось, застрял старый obj, а в новом коде в целях улучшения читаемости поубирали включение лишних хедеров и задели лишнее. XCode почему-то это не поймал и не стал перекомпилировать исходники.

Только оно все равно не поможет - чтобы наверняка, нужно еще и устройство-симмулятор чистить, а вот это заказчики забывают ну очень часто.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если речь идёт именно о том, чтобы научить заказчика делать очистку минимальными усилиями, то лучше попробуйте подсказать ему для Xcode комбинацию клавиш: Command + Alt + Shift + K (Clean build folder) - это решает не меньше, чем половину проблем с временными файлами Xcode.

Более сложное предприятие:

Создайте в корне своего проекта файл Rakefile:

```
require 'rake'

desc 'Clear derived data, reset Simulator, quit Simulator'
task :clean do
  system <<-'CLEAN'
   killall "iPhone Simulator" # Убивает Симулятор
   rm -rfv YourApp.app.dSYM.zip # По вкусу удаляет
   rm -rfv YourApp.ipa # архивы вашего приложения
   rm -rfv /Users/stanislaw/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/**/Applications/* # Удаляет ВСЕ временные данные всех версий симуляторов
  rm -rfv ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YourApp* # Удаляет Derived Data
  CLEAN
end
```

И потом запускайте в консоли

```
rake clean
```

Более полной очистки я никогда не делаю - этот скрипт работает на ура. Для работы вам нужно, чтобы был установлен язык Ruby. Или перепишите всё это на Bash, как советует [[@Bimawa](/users/10304/bimawa)](/users/10304/bimawa).

Comment: Обновит ответ. Скрипт использует Ruby/Rake

Comment: а синоним ~ вместо /Users/stanislaw для ruby не сработает? В баше точно пашет, а вот на раби как-то не писал

Comment: Вы правы, конечно, подойдёт. system - это отправка всего этого добра в тот самый Bash. Не было времени это достаточно абстрагировать.

Answer (score 3):

Напишите маленький bash скриптик с вызовом [clean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19092297/887325) и запуском проекта. И заставьте заказчика запускать проект через этот файлик.

п.с. прокет билдится, так то в ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ таким образом билд проекта ни как не должен лежать рядом с сорцами и, следовательно, не попадет в git.

Comment: я пробовал - не сработает, вот что делает для очистки одного и того же файла коммандная утилита:

    builtin-rm -rf /var/folders/_c/lwll9pq54k54kmq8pcch9fmc0000gp/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/AlertTest-Prefix-hbklilzjrcuytocnqlsogcvuguoa/AlertTest-Prefix.pch.pch

и Xcode:

    builtin-rm -rf /Users/aknew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlertTest-ftcbkcfwvsagrjdrgikkapshutgq/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/AlertTest-Prefix-cepeftjzycrblybojmrthwmkzqcq/AlertTest-Prefix.pch.pch

как видите, у них разные папки под билд

Comment: но если найти что именно очистит папку проекта, то это можно прописать не отдельным скриптом, а куском сборки - см. http://www.runscriptbuildphase.com/